# How two Autonomous systems connect with each other?

Tags: routing

How 2 ASes connect with each other? Is there just a link (cable) between two, or it has to be an IXP (Internet Exchange Point) there to link 2 ASes?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tecnhnically they can be interconnected by any link layer that can carry the IP packets between the two routers.

The interconnections between ASs can be roughly divided into transit (where a provider AS providers "internet access" to a customer)  and peering (where two ASs exchange routes for themselves and their customers with each other). There are also possibilities in between conventional transit and conventional peering which I won't go into here.

Transit connections will usually be over private links (though some exchange points do allow transit relationships). So will high traffic peering interconnections. The details of these private links will depend on the distance between the routers that need to be connected. For links within a datacenter most datacenters offer cheap and simple cross-connects. For longer distance links a circuit will likely be rented from a local communication provider. The rented circuit may either be a physical fiber, a wavelength on WDM or some kind of virtual circuit (MPLS, Vlan, ATM PVC etc).

Exchange points are used where an AS wants to peer with a large variety of other ASs but each individual peering relationship doesn't have enough traffic to justify a dedicated link. The exchange point provides connectivity between many ASs allowing the costs of physical interconnect to be spread across many peering relationhips. The exchange point typically provides an ethernet network over which the peering relationships can be established and each provider connects their router to that network (again this connection may be a simple cross-connect within a datacenter or it may be a longer distance link rented from a communication provider).

Answer (score 2):

Both are used very often: private interconnects are often used between a BGP transit customer and its upstream networks as well as between networks which need to exchange a lot of traffic, to offload this traffic from IXP links. BGP sessions via IXPs are often used to connect with a lot of networks without having to set up private interconnects with each network.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are used for interconnecting 2 ASes. Think this, right now, yor are located is some place on earth, and your network belong to some provider who is been announcing to the internet by some AS. Then, you can reach eg, Microsoft, who i'm not sure, but i think belong to another AS how maybe is located at the other side of earth, what i saying is that between you and the whole internet, exist a lots of ASes where your network(your IP belong to that network) is announced. Also, maybe, by some case, you access one IP that is located in some AS beside you